# Error on MessageChannel:"No function was found that matched the signature provided"

Tags: javascript

when I use `MessageChannel` and trigger `sendMsg` event, I get the error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'MessagePort': No function was found that matched the signature provided`.

I know little about it, could someone give some advice?

a.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="block">
    <iframe src="/messaging/channel-messaging/b" />
    <iframe src="/messaging/channel-messaging/c" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('message', e => {
      if (e.ports.length !== 0) {
        window.frames[1].postMessage('initPort', '*', e.ports)
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

b.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="block">
    <p>
      <input type="text" v-model="msg">
      <button @click="sendMsg">send</button>
    </p>
    <p>c say：{{ receiveMsg || 'nothing' }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      msg: '',
      receiveMsg: '',
      port: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const mc = new MessageChannel()
    this.port = mc.port2
    window.parent.postMessage('B has loaded', '*', [mc.port1])
    mc.port2.onmessage = e => {
      this.receiveMsg = e.data
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendMsg() {
      if (this.port) {
        this.port.postMessage(this.msg, '*')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

c.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="block">
    <p>
      <input type="text" v-model="msg">
      <button @click="sendMsg">send</button>
    </p>
    <p>b say：{{ receiveMsg || 'nothing' }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      msg: '',
      receiveMsg: '',
      port: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.parent.postMessage('C has loaded', '*')
    window.addEventListener('message', e => {
      if (e.data === 'initPort') {
        this.port = e.ports[0]
        this.port.onmessage = e => {
          this.receiveMsg = e.data
        }
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    sendMsg() {
      if (this.port) {
        this.port.postMessage(this.msg, '*')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Window.postMessage, [MessageChannel.port.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort/postMessage) doesn't have an `origin` argument, since there is only one other correspondant to this MessageChannel, that you already did trust.

So `"*"` in `port.postMessage(msg, "*")` is actually passed as what should be a *transferList*, but it is not [transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable), hence the error.

```js
const channel = new MessageChannel();
channel.port1.postMessage('foo', '*'); // throws
```

Simply remove it and you'll be fine.